# Are the http access logs for Google Cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

We are using Google Cloud functions for the api layer. These functions are http-triggered. We are looking for logs of http requests made to the functions. Do such logs exist?

The goal is instrumentation on frequency, source, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_logging_api), which is the main logging provider for GCP. These logs may look different that common Apache/Nginx logs, but one can also log custom events. These logs exist, as soon as one connects that client, which then logs something. The mere advance is, that one doesn't have a log file and one there, but all the logs within a uniform, consolidated GUI (when using this with GCE containers, this even gets more obvious, when there are a few instances).

Comment: So basically I need to capture and log this information myself. It isn't captured by google in any way? I have poured through stackdriver logs and haven't found anything around request source. More accurately, nothing around the request at all

Comment: I don't have any Cloud Function at hand which logs to StackDriver (so I cannot tell for certain), but if the logs are not sufficient for what you need, it's no problem to log custom payloads, on demand... also see [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging), because when setting this up properly, it's easy to filter these logs.

Comment: For logging HTTP requests, see this [example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/master/samples/http-request.js).

Comment: Thanks @martin-zeitler. I guess that does mean we need to log it ourselves.

Comment: I don't think you have to add any explicit logging statements.  I just ran a test and see log records being written to Stackdriver without a single explicit log in my Cloud Function code.   The log I looked at was:  logName: "projects/[MY-PROJECT]/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"

Comment: Thank you @Kolban. Those logs, from what I have found, don't contain request information. For example I couldn't query that data and determine, source ip, path, method, etc. We have ended up writing this data to logs via middleware

Comment: @Brettski When logging the requests manually, one could add further application-specific data to the entries, which usually isn't supported by the common access/error logs.

Comment: The goal was hopefully this basic information was available, like it is with the nginx logs from appengine. Since they are not, okay, we'll roll our own. Prefer not to if not needed, if you know what I mean. It also appears there is a proxy product, https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions, in beta which may be smart to put in front of our functions. It will have this data. I am assuming its a result of Google Apagee purchase.